# What is the lifetime of the result of std::string::c_str()?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, lifetime, c-str

In one of my programs, I have to interface with some legacy code that works with `const char*`.

Lets say I have a structure which looks like:

```
struct Foo
{
  const char* server;
  const char* name;
};
```

My higher-level application only deals with `std::string`, so I thought of using `std::string::c_str()` to get back `const char*` pointers.

But what is the lifetime of `c_str()`?

Can I do something like this without facing undefined behavior?

```
{
  std::string server = "my_server";
  std::string name = "my_name";

  Foo foo;
  foo.server = server.c_str();
  foo.name = name.c_str();

  // We use foo
  use_foo(foo);

  // Foo is about to be destroyed, before name and server
}
```

Or am I supposed to immediately copy the result of `c_str()` to another place?

Comment: Happened to me when I defined a local string in a function and returned `.c_str()`. I didn't understand why sometimes I get only parts of the string, until I understood that the `const char*` does not live forever, but until the string is destroyed

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `c_str()` result becomes invalid if the `std::string` is destroyed or if a non-const member function of the string is called.  So, usually you will want to make a copy of it if you need to keep it around.

In the case of your example, it appears that the results of `c_str()` are used safely, because the strings are not modified while in that scope.  (However, we don't know what `use_foo()` or `~Foo()` might be doing with those values; if they copy the strings elsewhere, then they should do a true *copy*, and not just copy the `char` pointers.)

Comment: c_str() pointer could be invalid if the std::string object is a automatic object going out of scope or in call to a thread creating function.

Comment: Can you please explain `non-const member function of the string is called.`?

Comment: A "non-const member function" is any member function that is not marked with the `const` keyword. Such a function might mutate the string's contents, in which case the string might need to reallocate the memory for the null-terminated version of the string returned by `c_str()`.  For example, `size()` and `length()` are `const`, so you can call them without worrying about the string changing, but `clear()` is not `const`.

Answer (score 27):

Technically your code is fine.

**BUT** you have written in such a way that makes it easy to break for somebody that does not know the code. For c_str() the only safe usage is when you pass it as a parameter to a function. Otherwise you open yourself up-to maintenance problems.

Example 1:

```
{
  std::string server = "my_server";
  std::string name   = "my_name";

  Foo foo;
  foo.server = server.c_str();
  foo.name = name.c_str();

  //
  // Imagine this is a long function
  // Now a maintainer can easily come along and see name and server
  // and would never expect that these values need to be maintained as
  // const values so why not re-use them

  name += "Martin";
  // Oops now its broken.

  // We use foo
  use_foo(foo);

  // Foo is about to be destroyed, before name and server
}
```

So for maintenance make it obvious:

Better solution:

```
{
  // Now they can't be changed.
  std::string const server = "my_server";
  std::string const name   = "my_name";

  Foo foo;
  foo.server = server.c_str();
  foo.name = name.c_str();

  use_foo(foo);    
}
```

But if you have const strings you don't actually need them:

```
{
  char const* server = "my_server";
  char const* name   = "my_name";

  Foo foo;
  foo.server = server;
  foo.name   = name;

  use_foo(foo);
}
```

OK. For some reason you want them as strings:
Why not use them only in the call:

```
{
  std::string server = "my_server";
  std::string name = "my_name";

  // guaranteed not to be modified now!!!     
  use_foo(Foo(server.c_str(), name.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is valid until one of the following happens to the corresponding `string` object:

- the object is destroyed
- the object is modified

You're fine with your code unless you modify those `string` objects after `c_str()`s are copied into `foo` but before `use_foo()` is called.

Answer (score 4):

Return value of c_str() is valid only until the next call of a nonconstant member function for the same string

Answer (score 3):

The `const char*` returned from `c_str()` is only valid until the next non-const call to the `std::string` object. In this case you're fine because your `std::string` is still in scope for the lifetime of `Foo` and you aren't doing any other operations that would change the string while using foo.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here's a [reference and quotation from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

> The pointer obtained from `c_str()` may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the `string`, excluding `operator[]`, `at()`, `front()`, `back()`, `begin()`, `rbegin()`, `end()` and `rend()`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the string isn't destroyed or modified, using c_str() is OK. If the string is modified using a previously returned c_str() is implementation defined.