# Differences in use of c_str() when returning a value from a function

Tags: c++, string

If I have the following two functions

```
std::string foo1()
{
    std::string temp;
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

and

```
const char* foo2()
{
    std::string temp;
    ...
    return temp.c_str();
}
```

and a function that takes a const char* as input;

```
void bar(const char* input) { ... }
```

Which one is safer to do:

```
bar(foo1().c_str());
```

or

```
bar(foo2());
```

If all I want to do is pass a string as an input to bar and then not care about the return value of either `foo` function will it actually matter?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I wouldn't do something like this in C (I'd return a malloc'ed pointer) but I wasn't sure what C++ was doing behind the scenes when converting a std::string to a const char*.

Comment: If it helps, in C++ `std::string` is the equivalent of the malloc'ed pointer. It just happens to free and strcpy and so on automatically. C++ requires a way of thinking quite different from C.

Comment: That's how I thought about it and fooled myself that this was the case for returning a c_str() too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const char* foo2()
{
    std::string temp;
    ...
    return temp.c_str();
}
```

`foo2()` is unsafe, you are returning a `const char*` to a local variable which will point to garbage when the function returns.

Just use `foo1` which is a safe and idiomatic way in C++ to return an object. [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) may kick-in 
which will elide the copy of temp  when `foo1` returns.

```
std::string foo1()
{
    std::string temp;
    ...
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const char* foo2()
{
    std::string temp;
    ...
    return temp.c_str();
}
```

isn't safe at all, as `temp` will be destroyed, so you'll be returning a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2):

bar(foo2()); is just plain wrong... because when foo2 returns, the temp std::string is destroyed and the pointer returned by c_str() now points to an invalid location.

Answer (score 2):

The character array of c_str is valid as long as the original string object is not destroyed. [This has been asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime). At the end of your function, `temp` is destroyed, which means `foo2()` return an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The `foo2` version is unsafe because the pointer returned by `c_str()` is invalidated as the `std::string` `temp` is destroyed when returning from `foo2`. `foo1` is safer as it returns a copy of the `std::string` `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

`foo2` returns a pointer to the internals of a local variable that is destroyed when going out of the function. (That's bad)