# c_str returned but missing first char

Tags: c++, string, return-value

```
const char* getOutPath() 
{
  return classVarStr.c_str();
}
```

I have the previous function,

there is something weird when I receive the returned value,

I get the full path but not including the first character!

so if the path is `results/appName_subStr.dat` I get `esults/appName_subStr.dat` !

I changed the function call to

```
string getOutPath() 
{
  return classVarStr;
}
```

then I call `c_str()` after receiving the value to get the path correct with the first `char`

I was guessing that it could be happening because of the function stack pop could have modified the address somehow?

anyone faced similar problem, and what could have been the cause?

**EDIT:**

```
class X
{
private:
    string classVarStr;
public:
    X(string in) : classVarStr(in)
    const char* getOutPath() 
    {
      return classVarStr.c_str();
    }
    string getOutPathStr() 
    {
      return classVarStr;
    }
}

class B
{
private:
    X xinstance;
public:
    B(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
         getSomepathFn(argc, argv);
    }

    string getAppPath1() 
    {
        return xinstance.getOutPath(); // this create a string then pass a copy, and internally deleted
    }
    const char * getAppPath2() 
    {
        return xinstance.getOutPathStr().c_str();// this is a problem, create a string, then pass const to the data, and deleted before the function call return, **Undefined behaviour** because the `getOutPathStr()` doesnt return a const reference
    }

}

class appObj
{
     void printMessage()
     {
         B obj = getBObj();
         FILE *fileptr = fopen(obj->getAppPath2(), "a");// this is the faulty area
     }
};
```

Comment: Please show the code you call `getOutPath()`.

Comment: We need to see more code, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it could be an object lifetime issue but we won't know until we see more.

Comment: Could you assemble a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces this problem?

Comment: How are you viewing the path?

Comment: string is a private member of the class, and the class is available during the whole app life time, I will show more code after lunch time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your function uses `std::string` with automatic storage duration, returning a pointer to its internal storage will yield ***undefined behavior*** since the object is automatically destructed once the execution goes out of scope (the memory where the actual characters resided is freed as well):

```
const char* getOutPath() 
{
    std::string classVarStr;
    ...
    return classVarStr.c_str();
}
```

That's the reason why the same code that returns a copy of local `std::string` object (by value) works as expected.

---

This code (from your edit):

```
const char * getAppPath2() 
{
    return xinstance.getOutPathStr().c_str();
}
```

calls `getOutPathStr()` that returns `std::string` object by value, which means that inside the `getAppPath2()` method, there is a copy of this `std::string` object. But this copy exists only within this scope as well, it is equivalent to:

```
const char * getAppPath2() 
{
    std::string copy = xinstance.getOutPathStr();
    return copy.c_str();
}
```

which is exactly the case that I have described at the beginning ~> the cause of UB.

Comment: Who is downvoting us? I think your response might be helpful. I've deleted mine in disgust. Have a +1

Comment: @doctorlove: I don't know but the downvote from my answer was removed already. You shouldn't delete your answer just because someone downvotes you with no explanation.

Comment: it is not, string is a private member of the class, and the class is available during the whole app life time, I will show more code

Comment: I got the issue, the function call return a newly created string, which I didnt notice because it was passed back by value, NOT a const string & getString()

Comment: i was confused because I had three layers of classes

Answer (score 1):

The char pointer returned by `c_str()` is only valid while `classVarStr` is exists or is unchanged. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime) If you have done anything after that call which changes the string, the char array will change.

The second version copies the string so is much safer.

Comment: it could be the issue, however I am trying to reintroduce the issue, to find out what caused it, up-voted to make it 0 :D