# Unexpected results when getting a const char * directly from a std::ostringstream with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following code with Visual Studio 2013 produces unexpected results when getting a `const char *` directly from a `std::ostringstream` but correct results when using a intermediate `std::string`. Why is that?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Hello work" << std::endl;

    const char *charPtr = oss.str().c_str(); // Unexpected results

    std::string str = oss.str();
    const char *charPtr2 = str.c_str(); // OK

    std::cout << "charPtr is: " << charPtr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "charPtr2 is: " << charPtr2 << std::endl;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

**Produces**

```
charPtr is:
charPtr2 is: Hello work
```

Comment: Please define _unexpected results_...

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: http://ideone.com/SucI6z sounds like "not real code"

Comment: I use Visual studio 2013.

Comment: @Korchkidu - are you _sure_ (I mean - _really sure_) this is the real code?

Comment: That is the real code. I'm using visual studio too. Pointing to a undefined location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pointer returned by `c_str()` is managed by the `std::string` instance over which `c_str()` is called.

Now, in that line, you are calling `c_str()` over the return value of `str()`, which is a temporary value that is destroyed at the end of the statement.

So, your resulting `const char *` variable ends up containing a pointer to already freed memory, which gives all sort of problems; technically, it's undefined behavior, i.e. anything can happen, including "seemingly work" if that memory hasn't been already reassigned/overwritten.

If instead you save the result of `str()` you don't have problems, since, as long as the `std::string` variable is alive, it will keep alive its buffers as well (but remember that any modification of an `std::string` invalidates any previous pointer returned by `c_str()`).

Comment: Then why is it working with GCC? Is it GCC which is too permissive?

Comment: @Korchkidu - because it's undefined behavior, meaning - anything can happen.

Comment: @Korchkidu, the behavior may change depending on compiler options, compiler version, current memory layout etc.

Comment: basic_string basic_ostringstream::str() const; +1

Comment: It seems safer then to just use the std::string and std::string.c_str() in function requiring a const char *. Or copy the const char * right away in a "safe place".

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *charPtr = oss.str().c_str(); // Unexpected results
```

`oss.str()` returns a temporary string. Temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full-expression that creates them - in this case, at the end of the statememt. This leaves `charPtr` dangling, pointing to memory that was deallocated when the temporary string was destroyed. Using that pointer gives undefined behaviour.

```
std::string str = oss.str();
const char *charPtr2 = str.c_str(); // OK
```

Now you're assigning the string to a variable, with automatic storage duration. This won't be destroyed until it goes out of scope, so the pointer is safe to use.

Comment: Ok, so this is Undefined Behaviour. That's why it works with GCC and not with Visual Studio 2013 (bugs excluded)?

Comment: @Korchkidu: You'll probably get different outcomes on different compilers, operating systems, optimisation settings, or phases of the moon, and some of these might match what you'd expect if the code "worked". It will depend on what happened to the deallocated memory before you access it - maybe it still contains the old string, maybe it's been reused and overwritten, or maybe it's been unmapped and will cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that some methods can return temporary entity which lifetime is limited by nearest ";" delimiter (end of statement).

So once you remember charPtr, it still alive but becomes invalid after the end of statement.
charPtr2 is more lucky because you create a copy of the string first, then capture the pointer. But anyway, take a look at this topic for detailed explanation, why you're not playing safe:
[What is std::string::c_str() lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime)

Answer (score 1):

To further corroborate the other answers, take a look at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/).

> Return value:
>   For (1), a string object with a copy of the current contents in the stream buffer.