# Returning char* goes wrong, print it good, return it badly (c++)

Tags: c++, char, return, stdstring

At this function i need to return a char* variable, before i return it, I print it and it prints well. what happened to the variable that makes the return variable wrong and why?

The function:

```
const char* NameErrorException::what() const throw()
{
     std::string str = "NameErrorException: name \'";
     str += _name;
     str += "\' is not defimed";
     std::cout << str.c_str()<< std::endl; //Prints good
     return str.c_str(); 
}
```

The print code:

```
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
   //Prints something like "▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌♀·┘v♦"
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

(NameErrorException inheritor from exception)

Thank you!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime).

Comment: str is a local variable and like all local variables, it will be collected at the end of the method.  If you return a valid pointer in the method, it will be invalid outside the method if it came from a local variable unless you allocated the space for it. This holds true also for returned pointers like c_str() unless you have reason to think that you're being returned a pointer that won't get destroyed later which is most certainly not your case.

Comment: Maybe not a necessarily a duplicate, but an answer to this problem is there for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string `str` will be destroyed once you leave the function. So the pointer you return is invalid, as it points to memory that is handled by the object. If the object is destroyed it will free this memory again.

Make `str` a member of the Exception and initialize it in the constructor.
Than your `what()` will return a valid pointer (as long as the exception object is valid).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class NameErrorException : public std::exception
{
    std::string m_what;
public:
    NameErrorException(std::string name)
        :m_what("NameErrorException: name \'" + name + "\' is not defined")
    {
    }

    const char* what() const throw() override
    {
        return m_what.c_str();
    }
};


int main() 
{
    try
    {
        throw NameErrorException("TEST");
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/878d5835db998300

Comment: Construction of `std::string` can throw an exception.   It's not necessarily a good idea to have an exception type that can throw as it is being constructed.   The result can be an unexpected exception being thrown.

Comment: @Peter Where would you recommend to construct the string? `what()` is `const`. I agree that this is might cause problems yet if `std::string` throws I also expect some other more serious issues.

Comment: Not actually the right question. What you need to decide is what exceptions need to be thrown, and implement the exception types accordingly.   If it doesn't matter to the caller if (for example) `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, then you can get away with constructing a string.  If the caller should only ever catch a `NameErrorException`, then make sure that type does not require constructing any `std::string` - or any other type that dynamically allocates memory (e.g. contain an array of char).

Comment: That seems a bit involved, but it's one way.

Answer (score 0):

`string::c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal memory used.

your `string` object is a local variable, it gets destroyed at the end of your function call, leading to an invalid memory access afterwards.

you should either use `strcpy` to a newly generated memory chunk or directly return a `std::string` object instead which would be the much safer option.