# Lifetime of returned strings and their .c_str()

Tags: c++, string, std, stdstring

I've come across multiple instance of this pattern (with boost::filesystem only used as example):

```
boost::filesystem::path path = ...;
someFunctionTakingCStrings(path.string().c_str());
```

where

```
const std::string path::string() const
{
  std::string tmp = ...
  return tmp;
}
```

Although I have never experienced problem with this pattern, I was wondering when the string returned by `sting()` is destroyed and whether the code accessing the `c_str()` is safe as the [c_str() lifetime is bound to std::string lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime).

Comment: Why is it tagged as a C question?

Comment: Because it has c_str() in it

Comment: @PhilLab: but that doesn't mean it would *compile* in C ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`someFunctionTakingCStrings(path.string().c_str());` is safe since the standard guarantees that the lifetime of the anonymous temporary `path.string()` survives the function call. So the pointer returned by `c_str()` is a valid parameter for `someFunctionTakingCStrings`.

`const std::string path::string() const` is safe since, conceptually, you are returning a value copy of `tmp`, although in practice a compiler will optimise out the value copy (a process called *named return value optimisation*).

Something like `const std::string& path::string() const` with the same function body as the one you have would **not** be defined (since the reference would *dangle*), and

```
const char* ub_server()
{
    std::string s = "Hello";
    return s.c_str();
}
```

is also undefined, as `s` is out of scope by the time the function returns.

Finally, note that taking a pointer to an anonymous temporary as a parameter in a function call is **not** allowed in standard C++ although annoyingly, Visual C++ allows it as an extension.

Comment: thanks. A quick follow-up: So, ``functionTakingPointer(&path.string())`` would also be safe?

Comment: @PhilLab: No it's unsafe in standard C++. I've put that at the end of the answer.

Comment: hm, then I have not understood the lifetime of path.string() completely. Or are anonymous temporaries a whole chapter on their own concerning memory management?

Comment: @PhilLab: That's pretty much the case, yes. Some nice reading for you over Christmas.