# C++ extern const char* not working as expected

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants, extern

I have worked with the extern keyword before but now I have a really strange problem.

First of all I have my common.hh File containing the declaration of extern variables:

```
//some extern declarations
extern const char* PATH;
```

In my main.cc I do the following (ignore the cout for now):

```
#include "common.hh"
const char* PATH;

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]){
PATH = somePath.c_str();
//std::cout << PATH << std::endl; //will print the correct path
//std::cout << std::string(PATH) << std::endl; //will fix the problem occuring later
//some function calls to other files where PATH is used
//... somePath still in scope ...
//... somePath is about to be destroyed
}
```

Now I have my other files Other.hh and Other.cc where the problem occurs:
First my Other.hh

```
#include "common.hh"
//function declarations and some other stuff
```

In Other.cc the problem when accessing PATH occurs:

```
#include "Other.hh"
void someFunction(...){
std::cout << PATH << std::endl; //When accessing PATH here again it prints garbage
```

In my file Other.cc I need the const char* PATH defined in main.cc but for some reason PATH has changed. The whole problem is fixed if I do std::string(PATH) somewhere in my main.cc as seen in the cout above. I don"t get what is wrong, all my other extern variables work just fine.

**EDIT:**
Problem is fixed for now. I just did the following in main.cc:

```
std::string tmp = somePath;
PATH = tmp.c_str();
```

I just don't understand why this fixes the problem because in theory `tmp` and `somePath` should have the same scope and should not be destroyed until after the function call in other.cc was executed. In other words: my function call in other.cc is before the scope of `somePath` has ended.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of `somePath.c_str()` is bound by the `somePath` variable.  As soon as it goes out of scope, `PATH` points to memory that will be re-used.

Can you make `PATH` a `std::string` instead of a `char*`?  If not, you will have to duplicate the value of `somePath.c_str()` using `strdup` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was fixed by doing string tmp = somePath; PATH = tmp.c_str(); but i still don't know why because both tmp and somePath should have the same lifetime. Before somePath is out of scope I work with PATH, so why did PATH change even if somePath.c_str() was still in scope?

Comment: You aren't modifying `somePath` after setting `PATH` are you?  `c_str` returns a raw pointer to the string's buffer. If you modify the string, then the buffer will be modified as well.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str` is a method of `std::string` which becomes invalid is the string is changed or destroyed. For example see details about `c_str`'s lifetimes in this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime).

You could either make `PATH` a `std::string` and let it make a copy or manually make a copy yourself into a `char *` having allocated enough memory. And then have a think about when to deallocate.

---

**Edit** - to respond to your edit

Where you have

```
std::string tmp = somePath;
PATH = tmp.c_str();
```

you claim "tmp and somePath should have the same scope" - they do not.
`PATH` is at global scope and you have assigned it here to point to `tmp`'s `c_str()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is fixed although I don't fully understand why. I edited my question to show that in main.cc some function call inside other.hh/cc is done where somePath should be still in scope and therefore not destroyed

Comment: when you assign `PATH` it will be ok, but if you try to read it later, after `tmp` has gone out of scope the pointer may well point at garbage.