# Why is there a difference between the value before return and the value after return?

Tags: c++, stdstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const char * substringAfterLast(const char * str, const char * separator)
{
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } 
    else if (str[0] == '\0' || separator == NULL || separator[0] == '\0') {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        string ret(str);
        size_t found = ret.find_last_of(separator);
        ret = ret.substr(found + 1);
        cout << "before value = [" << const_cast<char*>(ret.c_str()) << "]" << endl;
        return const_cast<char*>(ret.c_str());
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << "after value = [" << substringAfterLast("abc", "a") << "]" << endl;     
}
```

Result

```
before value = [bc]
after value = [**gabage value**]
```

Does the value disappear from memory at the end of the function?
I do not understand why these values change.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime

Answer (score 1):

The pointer you get back from `c_str()` is **strictly** a `const char*` type. Futhermore, it is only valid up to the earlier of the lifetime of the backing string `ret` or when `ret` is modified in any way.

The behaviour of any code that does not adhere to these principles, such as yours, is *undefined*.