# How to join a string and DWORD?

Tags: c++

There is this function :

```
void func(const char *)
```

and I wanna use it like :

```
DWORD dWrd = 19;
func("I am " + dWrd + " years old!")
```

thanks..

Okay, I got this another function very related to the question above, hope I don't violate any rules.

So what if I have this function that accepts an argument that it would print using `cout` and write to a file isinf fstream, what data type should I use?

`void myFunc(char c)` ?

`void myFunc(const char c)` ?

`void myFunc(const char *c)`?

Comment: Find a C++ beginner's tutorial, it will cover this ;)

Comment: _string_ like in `std::string` or like in C string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert everything to a `std::string` then use `c_str` to get a `const char*`

```
func(("I am " + std::to_string(dWrd) + " years old!").c_str())
```

To be a bit more verbose (and avoid the implicit conversions)

```
func((std::string("I am ") + std::to_string(dWrd) + std::string(" years old!")).c_str())
```

Be careful regarding what you do with the `const char*` within `func` as once the function returns [the temporary `std::string` will be destroyed and the pointer is no longer valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-stdstringc-str-lifetime).

Comment: ^^what Scheff said. We don't have enough information in the question to answer this with confidence.

Comment: This answers their question of how to concatenate strings and numeric values. If they have issues with memory management, they can elaborate their question or ask a new question.

Comment: well, not std::string, as mentioned above, it's like a C string, wasll this solution work?

Comment: If your function has the signature `void func(const char *)` yes this will work.

Comment: thanks, guess this answers everything. I'll try and accept this answer .

Answer (score 0):

Use of `std::ostringstream` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   DWORD dWrd = 19;
   std::ostringstream out;  
   out << "I am " << dWrd << " years old!";
   func(out.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: this seems a good answer but I think the code above will work better for my situation, since it only uses one line

Comment: @jordancedrick this is better, because its simplest than `std::to_string(dWrd)`

Comment: @jordancedrick If you want to concatenate more numbers with strings, you have to use of more statements to convert numbers to strings, BUT with `std::ostringstream` you just use of `<<` between numbers and strings....