# Assigning a std::string's c_str() result to that same std::string guaranteed safe by the standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

Is the following code guaranteed safe by the standard, with regards to `std::string`?

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() 
{
    std::string strCool = "My cool string!";
    const char *pszCool = strCool.c_str();
    strCool = pszCool;
    printf( "Result: %s", strCool.c_str() );
}
```

I've seen statements that indicate the result of `c_str` is only guaranteed safe to use until another method call on the same `std::string` is made, but it's not clear to me whether it's safe to pass that `const char *` back into the assignment method or not.

When tested using real-world compilers (GCC, Clang, and MSVC at their most recent versions) they all seem to support this behavior.

Furthermore, the compilers also support assigning a suffix of the string back to itself, e.g. `strCool = pszCool + 3` in this example; the result will be that the string has the same value as what was passed into it.

Is this behavior guaranteed somehow, or am I just lucky that the standard libraries provided by the compilers I've tested support this case?

Comment: Hi! You tagged this question `stl`, but it looks like you're using the C++ standard library. Which library are you using? See also [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/11082165) and the `stl` description.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've "tested" anything.  You merely saved a pointer to the C string, and verified nothing happened to crash.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456408/421195): `The c_str() result becomes invalid if the std::string is destroyed or if a non-const member function of the string is called. So, usually you will want to make a copy of it if you need to keep it around.`  In other words, a) ensure the original std::string remains unchanged, and/or b) strcpy() to another buffer.

Comment: Setting aside any morsels in the standard: I would expect a typical C++ library implementation to either allocate a new internal buffer before deleting the old one, or reuse the same buffer if the new string will fit. I would be surprised if the C++ standard mandates either behavior, so by default this becomes unspecified. And if the implementation chooses to reuse the buffer this becomes an overlapping copy, which is undefined behavior. That's my reasoning.

Comment: @paulsm4 I tested it by stepping through the code in a debugger and identifying e.g. memmove operations as noted, which doesn't translate well to a StackOverflow question, though I could've admitted as much.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, I meant to tag this with STD which has been helpfully fixed already :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++17, this was specified as:

`basic_string& operator=(const charT* s);`

*Returns:* `*this = basic_string(s)`.

*Remarks:* Uses `traits::length()`.

This sequence of operations guarantees that a copy is made before the original storage is destroyed.  While a standard library is not required to implement this call using this exact sequence of operations, it is required to have the same behavior as described.

In C++20, this wording was reworked, but I would be surprised if the meaning was changed.

Comment: This suggests an alternate form of the assignment that is always guaranteed to work, even if the standard changes: `strCool = std::move(std::string(pszCool));`

Comment: Yes, that would work, but my point is that it is already guaranteed to work.