# Undefined behaviour while modifying the Const* char array

Tags: c++

I have the below code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char* first[] = { "g", "kuchbhikarlobhai" };
    cout << "Address 0 =>" << &first[0] << endl;
    cout << "Address 1 =>" << &first[1] << endl;
    auto* second = &first;
    
    if(true) 
    {
        const std::string temp1 = "idontknowwhatis";
        const std::string temp2 = "slfjdslfkjdsf5f";
                       
        if(true) {
          (*second)[0] = temp1.c_str();
          (*second)[1] = temp2.c_str();
        }
    }
    for (const auto& third : *second) {
        cout << "Values: " << third << endl;
    }
}
```

The above code (https://ideone.com/eK44Hk) is working fine and `for loop` do print the updated value.

- But when I change the `temp1/temp2` to even a single char large, code fails and for loop prints garbage value. (https://ideone.com/2oVZAR)

```
const std::string temp1 = "idontknowwhatisa";
const std::string temp2 = "slfjdslfkjdsf5fb";
```

- And if I assign the same value directly to `(*second)[1]`, it works fine. (https://ideone.com/L6xHMV).

```
(*second)[1] = "slfjdslfkjdsf5fb";
```

**Question:**

1. Can anyone explain what is wrong here? Why the code is showing this behaviour?
2. If I understand correctly from the accepted answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char), `const char*` would mean, I won't be able to change the value. Then why the values are even getting modified in the above code?

Comment: First of all why are you still using "C" style arrays, and raw pointer arithmetic in C++? 
use `const std::array<std::string_view,2> first{ "g", "kuchbhikarlobhai" };` And take it from there.

Comment: Most of the code part is already present and I shouldn't be modifying them. I was updating a small part of the code where I will be changing the value of that array. So come up with this doubt.

Comment: `(*second)[0] = temp1.c_str();` becomes a dangling pointer when `temp1` dies, and same for the other variable, so dereferencing it after that is UB. If string length happens to affect something, that's likely due to whether the string fits into SSO or not. (Not that it ultimately matters.)

Comment: failing code and weird looking output is not necessarily undefined behavior. If you knew that the code has undefined behavior you wouldnt need to ask this question. Sorry, I am picking on wording, but I think it is worth to mention because "undefined behavior" is a well defined term and it does not mean "my code produces weird output"

Comment: When the `temp1` and `temp2` go out of scope, they are destructed.  The pointers are dangling.  Then you access the dangling pointers.  Hijinks and hilarity ensue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, what is SSO here?

Comment: It's all about *scope* and *life-time*. You define `temp1` and `temp2` in a specific scope. When that scope ends, so does the life-time of those variables and the objects are destructed.

Comment: SSO = [short (or small) string optimization](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/terms/6658/)

Comment: How should I be modifying these values if I do need to first define a std::string and then assign it to `(*second)`

Comment: What is your *actual* and underlying problem? Why do you need these assignments? How would that solve your original and actual problem? Please ask directly about that instead.

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please. Both of these questions have their own independent answers, that have nothing to do with each other. This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: use `temp1.c_str();` with caution. Its a pointer to an array owned by `temp1` and that pointer is only valid as long as `temp1` is alive. `(*second)[0] = temp1.c_str();` does not copy the string, it only copies a pointer. On the other hand, string literals lifetime is special

Comment: your actual problem is in the first line where you use an array of raw pointers, when you want an array of strings.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, that is legacy code and I won't be modifying it due to consistency with other codes.

Comment: `temp1` and `temp2` must remain alive as long as you're going to use those pointers.

Comment: ok, then accept that `const char* first[]` is an array of pointers to strings, not an array of strings and expecting it to be the latter leads to problems

Comment: for example 2) becomes clear when you consider that your code modifies the pointers in the array not the strings they point to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the lifetime of the result of std::string::c\_str()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-the-lifetime-of-the-result-of-stdstringc-str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the wisdom (or otherwise) of writing code like this (ok, it's not wise, but the OP says it's legacy code, we've all been there), there's an easy fix.

Just move the declarations of `temp1` and `temp2` outside the `if` statements.  Then, they will stay alive while you're still using them:

```
int main()
{
    ...

    const std::string temp1 = "idontknowwhatis";
    const std::string temp2 = "slfjdslfkjdsf5f";

    if(true) 
    {
                       
        if(true) {
          (*second)[0] = temp1.c_str();
          (*second)[1] = temp2.c_str();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that your issue is nothing to do with `const`.  It's to do with object lifetimes, as pointed out in the comments, and, if you're going to write code like this, you need to take due care that objects stay alive while they are still needed.

PS: Don't use `using namespace std`, it's a recipe for trouble.  If it's legacy code, put in the `std::` prefix on the parts of the code you're working on and, eventually, you'll be able to take it out.

Comment: Yeah, That `std` wasn't part of the actual code. I just mistakenly put `using namespace std`