# Out of scope issue?

Tags: c++, lifetime, stringstream

I am using a framework that has been working for years on CentOS 7.  We are migrating it to RHEL 8 and a few of the unit tests are failing. One in particular involves junk getting returned from what() on a std::runtime_error.  I created a very simple example that duplicates the problem.  It works on CentOS7 but not RHEL 8.  Here is the code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

const char * getString() {

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "some stuff to return" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "value to return: " << oss.str().c_str() << std::endl;

    return oss.str().c_str();
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    std::string value = getString();
    std::cout << "value returned: " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output for CentOS7 is:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ./a.out
value to return: some stuff to return

value returned: some stuff to return
```

while the output on RHEL8 is:

```
[user@localhost badoverload]$ ./a.out
value to return: some stuff to return

value returned: `
```

Is the value going out of scope and unavailable but the memory just happens to be untouched in CentOS 7?  Or is something else going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456359/what-is-the-lifetime-of-the-result-of-stdstringc-str

Comment: You can't return a `char*`  created by a `c_str()` from a `oss.str().c_str();` it is out of scope by the time the function returns. Return a `std::string` instead. Rule of thumb never return "raw pointers" (yes there are exceptions, but you need to really understand more about lifetime and ownership first)

Comment: "Works on CentOS 7" means "does not exhibit undesirable undefined behaviour".

Comment: *It works on CentOS7 but not RHEL 8* -- It really doesn't work on either one.  It's like saying "multiplication works by adding two numbers.  The two numbers I tested are 2 and 2".  Yes, that gives you 4 when you add 2 + 2 and 2 * 2.  But as soon as you try 3 + 3 and 3 * 3, things fall apart.  And who knows what would happen if the code changes (or version of the compiler changes, or compiler options change), and the CentOS7 no longer "works".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getString()` returns a dangling pointer here:

```
return oss.str().c_str();
```

The `std::string` returned by `str()` is temporary and gets destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the whole expression.

So, when you do...

```
std::string value = getString();
```

... that reads from the dangling pointer, the whole program has *undefined behavior*.

Just return a `std::string` instead of a `const char*`:

```cpp
std::string getString() {
    //...
    return oss.str(); // not c_str()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot return a string because the signature of what() for a std::runtime_error calls for a const char *.  I did create a local std::string attribute in the derived exception class and returning the c_str() of that worked.  I just wanted to verify that it was indeed an issue since it worked fine in CentOS 7.  Sounds like it is.

Comment: @mybodycravesbutterygoodness Who is responsible for deallocating that `const char*` ?

Comment: @mybodycravesbutterygoodness `std::runtime_error` already has storage for string and can be constructed from a `std::string`. Its `what()` function just returns a pointer to what the exception stores internally.  _"I did create a local std::string attribute in the derived exception"_ - No need if you derived from `runtime_error`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qsocqaTMs)

Comment: In other words, build-up your desired string when calling the `runtime_error`'s inherited constructor, not in an overridden `what()` method. ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6G3erzd7))

Comment: @TedLyngmo RemyLebeau Thanks for the tips.  I created a private operation to populate the string and fed the return value to the runtime_error constructor.  All is good now.